# How do I block the entire Internet except a few 'whitelist sites'?

Tags: internet, productivity

I need some method to block the entire Internet other then a few sites on my 'whitelist'. I am looking for a solution that is not browser specific - so no add-ons/plugin suggestions please. Is there any file within the system or some Command to run in the terminal that will allow me to do this ?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?  How are you connecting to the Internet?

Comment: You are probably looking for something like a firewall -- to give you a keyword to check for. A firewall limits access globally, and can work in both directions (from you to the internet and vice versa).

Answer (score 7):

You can consider Privoxy, available from the Ubuntu Software Center. It's a proxy server [that may do what you want](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/configuration.html).
Section 3.27 has this:

> 3.27. Can I set-up Privoxy as a whitelist of "good" sites?
>
> Sure. There are a couple of things you can do for simple
>   white-listing. Here's one real easy one:
>
> ############################################################
>
> ## Blacklist
>
> ######################################################
>
> { +block }  / # Block *all* URLs
>
> ############################################################
>
> ## Whitelist
>
> ######################################################
>
> { -block }
>   kids.example.com
>   toys.example.com
>   games.example.com
>   This allows access to only those three sites by first blocking all URLs,
>   and then subsequently allowing three specific exceptions.
>
> Another approach is Privoxy's trustfile concept, which incorporates
>   the notion of "trusted referrers". See the Trust documentation for
>   details.
>
> These are fairly simple approaches and are not completely foolproof.
>   There are various other configuration options that should be disabled
>   (described elsewhere here and in the User Manual) so that users can't
>   modify their own configuration and easily circumvent the whitelist.

Comment: I've installed privoxy but can't find this blacklist or whitelist anywhere.

Comment: Hi, I haven't yet re-installed Privoxy after doing a clean install of Lubuntu 13.04. But I will get around to it soonish :) I'll ping you then!

Comment: @JoshuaRobison, Looks like you solved your problem [here](http://superuser.com/q/589008/151227)?

Comment: and further more here : http://superuser.com/questions/393967/block-specific-url-on-web-browsers/589421#589421 :p